# Can anyone show me how to find e.g $\phi(1,−1,−2)$, given the scalar field $\phi(x,y,z) = 4yz^{3}+ 3xyz−z^{2}+ 2$?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, scalar-fields

I have a question in my applied calculus worksheet that I don't know how to work out.

> Given the scalar field $\phi(x,y,z) = 4yz^{3}+ 3xyz−z^{2}+ 2$. I need to find:
> (i)$\phi(1,−1,−2)$
> (ii)$\phi(0,−3,1)$
> (iii)$\phi(1,2,3)$

Does anyone know how does one do this?

Thanks

Aigars

Comment: Just plug in the values for $(x,y,z) $ in your scalar field.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that
$$\phi(1,-1,-2)=4(-1)(-2)^{3}+3(1)(-1)(-2)-(-2)^{2}+2$$
$$\phi(0,-3,1)=4(-3)(1)^{3}+3(0)(-3)(1)-(1)^{2}+2$$
and $$\phi(1,2,3)=4(2)(3)^{3}+3(1)(2)(3)-(3)^{2}+2$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Okay. So you plugged in the values in the equation. I tried that. Is that all that is required? 

For example φ(1,−1,−2) = 4(-1)(-2)^3 + 3(1)(-2)-(2)^2 + 2 = Some resultant

Is that the correct answer? Or is there something else that needs to be done as well?

Comment: You do not need to do anything else. You only have to solve the arithmetic operations that I left raised and that's all.

Comment: Ah cool, thanks!